# MongoDB Search and Save if conditions

Tags: php, mongodb

Ok, this seems like I might have to do mulitable mongodb search and inserts but thought I would ask.

I have an issue where we need to search the database for a business name if it is not in the db then add it, but if it is in the database then I need it to see if it is owned by the same user ID. if not return `"sorry we can not add this to your account."` followed by the userid of the correct owner.

I thought a simple

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("businessname" => $businessname));
```

would work but that would mean I would need to do the following

```
$collection = $this->db->retail_details;
$cursor = $collection->find(array("businessname" => $businessname));
if ($cursor->count() > 0)
{
SEARCH FOR OWNER
  if(OWNER != CURRENTUSER)
  {
return "Sorry You can not make changes please contact (OWNER)"
  }
}
else{
INSERT NEW LEAD
}
```

While i know that would work, i find that it could get messy.
As users that are managers need to be able to view and edit any leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should able to do this as an [upsert](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php) by matching on businessname and owner as your criteria.

> Upsert: If no document matches $criteria, a new document will be
>   created from $criteria and $new_object

Would be along the lines of:

```
<?php
    $collection = $this->db->retail_details;
    try {
        $collection->update(
            array("businessname" => $businessname, "owner" => $currentuser),
            $new_lead, // new lead document to insert
            array("upsert" => true, "safe" => true)
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong .. 
    }
?>
```